# Pass an object as parameter to the ServiceHost

Tags: wcf, web-services, hosting, ninject

I'm trying to start up a project which takes care of stuff. I call this class the `CentralLogic` class. When this is started, I'd like to start a host. The host has some settings in the `App.Config` file like the baseAddress and endpoints.

This host can interact with this `CentralLogic` class. I'd like to pass on the instantiated object to this host.

Currently, I'm trying something like this:

```
centralLogic = new CentralLogic();
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(centralLogic, typeof(KLAService));
using (host) 
{ 
    host.Open();
    //Start a WPF UI. Also makes sure the host stays open
    //as long as the UI stays open.       
    Application app = new Application();
    app.Run(new ConfigurationWPF.MainWindow(centralLogic));

    host.Close();
}
```

The KLAService is defined like this:

```
public class KLAService : IKLAService
{
    CentralLogic centralLogic;

    public KLAService(CentralLogic theCentralLogic)
    {
        centralLogic= theCentralLogic;
    }
    .....
}
```

This doesn't work (the creation of the ServiceHost is wrong, both in number of arguments and the second parameter). I can get it started without parameter by doing:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(KLAService));
```

So, the problem is that I don't know how to pass on the object on to the server. How do I do this?

EDIT: I tried the following:

```
centralLogic = new CentralLogic();
KLAService klaService = new KLAService(centralLogic);
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(klaService))
{ 
    host.Open();

    Application app = new Application();
    app.Run(new ConfigurationWPF.MainWindow(centralLogic));

    host.Close();
}
```

This popped an `InvalidOperationException`:

> In order to use one of the ServiceHost constructors that takes a
>   service instance, the InstanceContextMode of the service must be set
>   to InstanceContextMode.Single.  This can be configured via the
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute.  Otherwise, please consider using the
>   ServiceHost constructors that take a Type argument.

Comment: You can't pass an instantiated object to the `ServiceHost` (unless it's an instantiated service, which requires `InstanceContextMode.Single`, as you've discovered).  How do you want the host to interact with `CentralLogic`?  Giving some details around that may enable others to give you some different approaches to use.

Comment: You *could* have a method in your service that you could call and pass in `CentralLogic` to.  You could do that from within the creation of your `ServiceHost`.  But this seems like a bit of a hack and may not be the best way - it really depends on what `CentralLogic` is and how the service is supposed to interact with it.

Comment: CentralLogic is a class which is a sort of manager to all the stuff behind. So interaction with the database but also with hardware is managed from there (and classes instantiated in the CentralLogic again). Whenever my service starts, the CentralLogic should be initiated. My host should be able to, for example, push a new User-object into the CentralLogic class. That's why I'm trying to get the instantiated CentralLogic-class there.

Comment: So @Tim (forgot to tag you), what do you think is the best approach? I must admit I just rolled into the WCF-stuff so I'm not too experienced with it. But the service doesn't do much neither, besides getting a list of User's and having a method to store a User back.

Comment: There's a number of ways to approach this, and part of it depends on the design of `CentralLogic` and how it's used.  Does the service need to be using the same instance of `CentralLogic` that the WPF app is using?  Or is `CentralLogic` static?  Does `CentralLogic` require parameters in the constructor?  Depending on the answers to those questions I can give you at least one approach, probably two, and I'm sure there are others.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your response. The same instance of CentralLogic is being used everywhere (to ensure no data gets mixed up from different UI's). That's why I was thinking to make it static, perhaps that'll make things easier. CentralLogic doesn't have parameters (as you can see in my opening question, that code is accurate). I've been playing around a bit with `Ninject` yesterday to see if I could manage to gain an instance using that plugin, but I didn't get any further. I'm curious to hear about your suggestions! Thanks again for the effort!

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps should my servicehost start the `CentralLogic`. Then I'd need the UI to approach that host and communicate through there. Another possibility would be to initiate the UI in the `CentralLogic` itself. Then the local UI wouldn't have to use the `ServiceHost`. The WPF Browser Application I'm creating should approach the host, still, but that's the goal. What do you think?

Comment: You've got the beginnings of good ideas here.  I probably won't be able to respond until later tomorrow/today, as I'm in the midst of about 3 different production problems (in the middle of the night, of course).

Comment: Allright, no rush! I'll pick up some other things on the project and park the WCF-part for today. It's early in the morning here though! ;) Perhaps when you can find the time tonight/tomorrow, we can continue the discussion in chat? We'll figure out the time zones when you're done :) Good luck there!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea - my e-mail is in my profile, and I'm in PST (left coast of the US).  Feel free to shoot me an e-mail and we can either collaborate in chat or offline and then post the final solution here for future users.